# NLTK - throwing stem() missing 1 required argument error

Tags: python, anaconda, nltk, list-comprehension, curses

I'm following a tutorial on deep learning that uses anaconda here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICL7VRKvS_A&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-ndH9FoC4YWHGXG5RZekt-Q&index=4

The line it's complaining about: (edited as per michotross' suggestion)

```
words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?" and w is not None]
```

error shown is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/HP X360/PycharmProjects/Mach_Lrn/bot.py", line 30, in <module>
words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?" and w is not None]
File "C:/Users/HP X360/PycharmProjects/Mach_Lrn/bot.py", line 30, in <listcomp>
words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?" and w is not None]

TypeError: stem() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'
```

I'm fairly new to coding, had a bit of a google, but I've copied text from the tutorial that works on the video so am reaching out for a little help  which would be really appreciated :)

Anna x

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```py
words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w.lower() != "?" and w.lower() is not None]
```

If you want to see what's being passed to stemmer.stem then convert from list comprehension to regular loop:

```py
stemmed_words = []
for w in words:
    try:
        stemmed_words.append(stemmer.stem(w.lower()))
    except:
        print('WORD ->', w.lower(), '<-')
```

Comment: thanks for that, I've edited my top post to reflect your suggestion, it seems to have thrown the same error :(

Comment: I added an edit that you can use to figure out what is being passed to stemmer.stem

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, turns out he cut the video and missed out a couple of corrections on typos in the code i had to trawl through but i've managed to get it working by moving a couple of brackets where it was calling on stemmer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - was typo error in previous code.